# Breakpoint not hitting on ajax call

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to to do a `GET` ajax call to .aspx WebMethod but not getting breakpoint hitting to the Method. The strange thing is that I am not getting any error too neither at browser console nor at Visual Studio level. Here is ajax syntax.

```
var appName = "FSDB";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Default.aspx//ConvertDatadttoString",
    data: appName,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Hi");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I am getting the `"Hi"` message on success. Please help.

Update
Method Signature

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string ConvertDatadttoString(string appName)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int)); // Add five columns.
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailId", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(15, "Vikas", "gh.com");
        dt.Rows.Add(40, "Pankaj", "pa.com");

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the function signature? I guess its accepting a DateTime as parameter, which you are not suppyling thus breakpoints is not hit

Comment: Your AJAX call is working fine so it must be getting a response from somewhere. Are you sure you put the breakpoint in the right place?

Comment: @Satpal I have updated the post with Method code too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, breakpoint is at right place.

Comment: what javascript debugger do you use?

Comment: @Satpal tried `data: {appName: appName},` but still its not hitting

Comment: @madalinivascu IE Edge

Comment: Try with `url: "Default.aspx/ConvertDatadttoString?appName=" + encodeURIComponent(appName)` and remove `data` option

Comment: What are you getting with your `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @Satpal Tried but no luck.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am getting my Markup of the page in console.log

Comment: @Lara as you may have guessed, it's not hitting your function at all and instead is returning your Default.aspx page - which is why you're not getting the breakpoint.   The issue is with the `url` - without knowing more about your classes etc, it's only a guess, but try with: `url:"ConvertDatadttoString"`

Comment: @freedomn-m Tried but its giving wrong URL

Comment: @Satpal Any suggestion or workaround on this ?

Comment: You'll need to work out what the url should be for your situation.

Comment: I have got the solution.I will post it in sometime.Thanks all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I would say that GET requests are not allowed for page's webmethods by default. Try to decorate you webmethod with ScriptService attribute and set the UseHttpGet parameter value to TRUE as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string ConvertDatadttoString(string appName)
```

And ajax call should look like:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Default.aspx//ConvertDatadttoString?appName='" + appName + "'",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Hi");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```